# WinPE 5 x64 netdom alternatives

Tags: powershell, active-directory, 64-bit, sccm, winpe

We are currently testing deployments using WINPE 5 x64 and are running into issues when we need to pull OU information from AD/specify the location for a newly provisioned machine.

In previous versions, WinPE allowed the use of the netdom command, which we built inside an executable that added the machine to the correct ou. Sample snippet below. (Correct location is output to a text file for the task sequence to read).

```
        CString strPathToNetdom = (filebuf);
        CString Command = ("\"") + strPathToNetdom + _T("\\netdom.exe\" query ou /Domain:contoso.com /ud:CONTOSO\\SCCMADM /pd: > X:\\Windows\\Temp\\ou_list.txt") + _T("\"");       
        Command = _T("\"") + Command;
        CT2A ascii(Command);
```

I would just use powershell cmdlets, however WINPE5 out the box does not support the .net components to run powershell and the overhead of upwards of 90mb is something we aren't really too keen on.

Are there any alternatives that someone has come across?

Comment: Why not edit the WinPE and add the .NET components? It's fairly trivial, I've done it for [WinPE4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861933/net-gui-not-displaying-in-winpe), and used a C# app to pull OU info from AD. If that's something you can do, I'll post an answer on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using dsadd?

```
dsadd computer /?
```

for syntax and usage help.