# Winform GUI not showing up in WinPE

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winpe

I'm trying to run a small winform app (code is C#) on WinPE (latest build 14393). Calling the exe starts the application, but the GUI doesn't show up.
I injected .NET to PE via dism, so this is not the problem. Found a post where s.o. had the same problem, but I don't understand the solution. 
[.NET GUI Not Displaying in WinPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861933/net-gui-not-displaying-in-winpe)
I don't want to run powershell, because this would size up the PE boot.wim even more. It should be kept as small as possible.
Any ideas?

Comment: - To reduce its size, Windows PE includes only a subset of the
   available Win32 application programming interfaces (APIs). I/O (disk
   and network) and core Win32 APIs are included.



 - **Windows PE does not support the Microsoft .NET Framework or the
   Common Language Runtime (CLR).**

Comment: .NET framework is available as an optional package for WinPE, delivered with the ADK. As I wrote above, this package is already installed. 
**It is not correct, that .NET is not supported!**

Comment: I am telling you what was stated by Microsoft, not by me.[Read Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Your link is related to WinPE 2.0, which is a very early version. In those times, there was no .NET support in PE.
As I stated in my question, I'm using WinPE 14393 what is the latest build.

Comment: Since  your app uses .Net and  windows.forms namespace. You need to add the dependant packages when you build for WinPE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

walking through all those MS sites related to WinPE, I found the hint to success in starting my app. It works!

**Dependencies: Install WinPE-WMI before you install WinPE-NetFX.**

source:https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference